# Cutting board from previously stained wood

Tags: staining, safety, cutting-board

I purchased some lumber from a third party which included a large walnut slab that had previously been stained on one side (I don't know what it was). I wanted to turn it into a few cutting boards, so I cut it into pieces and passed them through my planer on both sides until it was flat and all stain was gone. Is safe to use as a cutting board, assuming I am going to oil it with mineral oil?

Comment: The general consensus here has been that all finishes, once dried/cured, are actually food safe. You'd probably want to wait for a few more folk to chime in, but while you're waiting, take a look through the [tag:staining], [tag:safety], [tag:finishing] and [tag:cutting-board] tags to get an idea.

Comment: *"passed them through my planer [until] all stain was gone. Is safe to use as a cutting board, assuming I am going to oil it with mineral oil?"* You've pretty much answered your own question here, since once all the stain was gone even if you did have concerns about it not being food safe they went away with the wood itself. So yes it's safe, even if you didn't intent oil it with mineral oil (see previous discussions on whether this is necessary, or even desirable).